# WebRTC over HTTPs Issue

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I have created a simple WebRTC application that works fine in testing overlocal host; However, WEBRTC isn't much use unless you have a secure connection, as browsers now will not run GetUserMedia unless you have HTTPs, so I am 'trying' to upgrade it for SSL-TLS. Below is a screen shot of my two applications side by side, one secure (*not working*) the other non secure (*works*)

[image]

As you can see above, localhost 'connects' while HTTPs 'can't establish connection'.  I am new to SSL, so this may be a simple one.  Just would appreciate some more eyes on this.

I do know my HTTPS server for the the Javascript is connecting securely, see image below[image]

Below are my code snippets.  Any help would be greatly appreciated:

**SSL Client - Client.JS**

```
var connection = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443'),

name = "";
```

**Non Secure Client - Client.JS**

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888'),

    name = "";
```

**Non Secure JS Server - index.JS**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,

wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8888 }),

users = {};
wss.on('connection', function (connection) {
connection.on('message', function (message) .....
```

**Secure JS Server - SSLindex.JS**

```
 Var https = require('https'),

fs = require('fs'),

 express = require('express'),

  app = express();


var wss = https.createServer({
key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),

cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),

ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.crt'),

requestCert: true,

rejectUnauthorized: false
 }, app).listen('8443', function() {
console.log("Secure Express server listening on port 8443");
});

 app.use("/", function(req, res, next) 
{
 res.send("index.js is working!");

  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For developers convenience chrome will treat `localhost` as a secure origin.
If you are using http://localhost or ws://localhost there is no SSL involved, so its working just fine in right side screenshot.
But for `https` or `wss`, browser will verify the SSL certificate authority.

> To resolve websocket connection issue with wss://localhost:8443/

Temporary work around: Open https://localhost:8443/ url and allow the browser exception by clicking Adavced => proceed
Actual Solution: Assign a domain name to your node server (node.kali2016.com) and configure node with Authorised SSL certificates. Then replace
`var connection = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443')`
with
`var connection = new WebSocket('wss://yourdomainname:8443')`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my EasyRTC page working over HTTPS by using my server's IP address instead of localhost.
So:
https://localhost:8443/ did not work. Returned Connection Closed error.
https://192.168.0.113:8443/ worked OK and showed the web page as it should.

This might work for someone else too.