# Heroku app not using https on iOS, but does on desktop Chrome

Tags: heroku, https, websocket, webrtc

I deployed a basic WebRTC test app to Heroku on a paid hobby dyno. It functions fine on Chrome running on Manjaro, but won't connect via https on iOS Safari. Uses websockets for signalling if that matters. Any help would be appreciated!

Test app:
https://webrtc-tstapp.herokuapp.com/

Repo:
https://github.com/TuxFan77/webrtc-test-app

Answer (score 0):

What is the browser when did you test?

Currently, Chrome on iOS doesn't support WebRTC API perfectly yet.

Try Safari.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention it was on Safari because of the reason you mentioned. I'll edit the original question. I actually got it working by changing location.protocol to https when not running on localhost. Not sure if that's a hack solution but it works for testing at least.

Comment: Oh, you're right. For WebRTC, most of cases, getUserMedia is required. But without SSL, you can not use that API. I recommend you glance at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901648/webrtc-over-https-issue/43907285) :)